# Pycaret setup for one hot encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pycaret

I'm stuck in a problem with one hot encoding for categorical variables in Pycaret. The problem is that even setting my categorical variables, the pipeline apply normalization to categorical variables, and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

At first, using the code below everything works fine:

```
from pycaret.classification import *
from pycaret.datasets import get_data
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
dataset = get_data('income')
dataset.dtypes
```

Until I start the setup and

```
exp_clf01 = setup(  data = dataset
                  , target = 'income >50K'
                  , session_id = 123
                  , numeric_features = ['age','education-num','capital-gain','capital-loss','hours-per-week']
                  , categorical_features = ['workclass','education','marital-status','occupation','relationship','race','sex','native-country']
                 )
df_transformed = get_config("X_train")
df_transformed.head()
```

After try look the head of data frame it only applies the one hot enconding to the column `race` and normalizes the others categorical inputs and I can't figure out why.

| age | workclass | education | education-num | marital-status | occupation | other colums |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 46.0 | 0.303273 | 0.271186 | 11.0 | 0.101942 | 0.484643 | ... |
| 27.0 | 0.218620 | 0.412939 | 13.0 | 0.044165 | 0.484643 | ... |
| 33.0 | 0.218557 | 0.568315 | 14.0 | 0.448894 | 0.455449 | ... |
| 60.0 | 0.218557 | 0.412673 | 13.0 | 0.448894 | 0.484286 | ... |
| 25.0 | 0.218620 | 0.063798 | 6.0 | 0.044165 | 0.229692 | ... |

How can I prevent this behavior?